# React native html encoding

Tags: react-native

I want to encode a link in react native, no idea which library to use. example [link](https://www.url-encode-decode.com/)

```
original 1: HSBC Holdings PLC
original 2:Software & Services
encoded 1: HSBC+Holdings+PLC
encoded 2:Software+%26+Services
```

what i tried :

```
import { encode } from "html-entities";
encode("Software & Services", { mode: "nonAsciiPrintable", level: "html5" })
```

what i got:

```
Software &amp; Services
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the type of conversion you're looking for (which I'm assuming are the examples you put first in your question), you can use `encodeURIComponent` -- this is built in to Javascript -- no library required. By default, that uses `%20` for spaces, so you can convert those with RegEx to the pluses:

```
encodeURIComponent("Software & Services").replace(/%20/g, "+")
```

The HTML entities library you referenced is a little different -- it converts the special charters for use in HTML, not a URL like the examples that you gave.